# Screen navigate from stacknavigator is not working when using bottomtabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm new to react native, and I've problem with navigating between one of my screen to another.
I'm using stacknavigator like this:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Splash: { screen: SplashScreen},
        Mobile:{screen:MobileAuthentication} ,
        Code:{screen:CodeAuthentication} ,
        Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
        ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
        ProfileDetails: { screen: ProfileDetails },
    },
    { initialRouteName: 'Splash'}
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

In my homeScreen I am using buttomtabnavigator

```
const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    A: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
...
      }
    },
    B: {
      screen: FilterScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
...
      }
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FilterScreen',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#3F51B5'
    }
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(bottomTabNavigator);
```

The problem is that when I want to navigate from `ProfileScreen` to `ProfileDetails` by `onpress` then it's not working

```
       <ProfileBtn
          onPress={() => {
            console.log('item Clicked'),
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileDetails')
          } }
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to pass "navigation" into your stackNavigator creation, using the options with smthg like this (for each of your stack screen or at least those within which you want to use it) :

```
options={({route, navigation}) => (
                {headerTitle: 'Splash',
                route: {route}, 
                navigation: {navigation}}
            )}
```

If that's not the answer, please provide us with the error you get in your console.